# Pyaudio and/or time being glitchy

Tags: python

I was able to work out an issue where it wouldn't play sound at all. Now I have an arguably worse issue. It plays the Eevee.wav file, but only once. Any clue?

```
    #importing stuff
from playsound import playsound
import keyboard
import speech_recognition
import pyttsx3
import pyaudio
import time

#data load
PetHappyTF = 2
def countdown(PetHappyCD):
    while PetHappyCD > 0:
        PetHappyCD -= 1
        time.sleep(1)
    PetHappyTF += 1    

#first bootup
playsound('Bootup.wav')

#Program
while True:            
    if PetHappyTF >= 1:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("E"): #Keystroke standing in for touch sensor. Eevee.wav standing in for Happy sound
            playsound('Eevee.wav')
            PetHappyTF = 0

seconds = 15
seconds = int(seconds)
PetHappyCD(seconds)
```

Comment: Because you set `PetHappyTF` to 0 after then first time... Then the condition `if PetHappyTF >= 1` doesn't hold anymore and you just have an infinite loop...

Comment: Sorry, bit of a Python noob here, could you elaborate and point out a bit please?

Comment: You have a `while True` loop. Inside it, after playing the file, you do `PetHappyTF = 0`. The following iterations, the condition `if PetHappyTF >= 1` will never be true again (because `0 < 1`) so the file will not play and you just have an infinite loop

Comment: So do I just have to add `PetHappyCD == 15 ` ?

Comment: I have no idea what that loop is supposed to do. I can only tell you that this is the reason it doesn't work... How you fix it depends on what your code is doing which you didn't really say

Comment: Yeah sorry lol. This is the beginning of the script for a Furby like toy. The script under program is supposed to play the .wav then wait 15 seconds until it can make the noise again, even if you hit e (Which is a stand in) Sorry if I'm being annoying but I just cant figure this out

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Then remove the variable completely. Just do `time.sleep(15)`...